# SSIS Unix timestamp to SQL Server datetime from csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, unix-timestamp

I have tried several options to get this to work but have so far been unsuccessful using the derived column to transform Unix to datetime.

The column in question is loaded in as a **DT_WSTR** (I have also tried DT_I4 and DT_I8) and the derived column is then supposed to create the new column with the datetime.

This is what i currently have:

```
DATEADD("ss", (dt_i4)[logged_date], (dt_date)("1970-01-01"))
```

When I try to execute i get an error at the derived column which just states

> "An error has occurred while evaluating the function"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to put the square brackets on the post. Edited to reflect. Logged date is a column from the csv flat file.

Comment: Sorry, which is the type inside the logged_date? Is it consistent with the cast?

Comment: The logged_date column has Unix timestamps. I have tried casting it as both a string and an integer from the source but the derived column conversion fails when trying to use the SSIS DATEADD function.

Comment: Try to modify DataType output column (
which corresponds to logged_date)  in your Flat File Source Editor: Property -> Show Advanced Editor -> Input and Output properties -> Output Columns.

Comment: Unfortunately that's something I do every time i make a column datatype change and even that still hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem.

Turns out there was a row with a null valued unix date which is why SSIS was having a problem with the conversion.

I have set up an error output to place into an excel file should it happen again.

Code is now working as expected.

Appreciate the help that was offered.

Answer (score 0):

If your Timestamp is in seconds

```
Select dateadd(SS,1476444566,'1970-01-01') Returns 2016-10-14 11:29:26.000
```

If micro-seconds (requires a little more workd(

```
Declare @UnixTime bigint = 1470562081943371
Select DateAdd(MS,round(((@UnixTime/1000000.)-(@UnixTime/1000000))*1000,0),DateAdd(SECOND,(@UnixTime/1000000),'1970-01-01 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: I am considering just doing it through SQL Server but would require me to create a new table to accept the Unix timestamp before setting up an SP to convert to datetime. I am ideally looking for a solution in SSIS so I don't have to create a workaround for it.

Comment: @ChristopherDonnelly SSIS can handle the conversion.  Just take a harder look at the syntax in my first line

Comment: I am bringing in the data from a csv flat file source and I don't see a way of injecting SQL to achieve the SQL DATEADD function. I tried putting in the first line you suggested into my derived column function but get an invalid token error. Is there something I am missing?